# Java subclass of JButton overriding setEnabled method problem

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, jbutton, method-hiding

I have a custom button class called ImageButton that extends JButton. In it i have a setEnabled method that I want to be called rather than the JButton's setEnabled method.

My code is below. In my other class I create a new instance of ImageButton, but when I try to use the setEnabled method, it goes straight to the JButton's setEnabled method. Even before I run the code, my IDE is telling me that the ImageButton's setEnabled method is never used. If I change the method to "SetOn" it works fine. So why is it that I can't use the same name as that of the super class? I thought it's supposed to hide the superclass method if it's the same name?

```
public class ImageButton extends JButton{

    public ImageButton(ImageIcon icon){
        setSize(icon.getImage().getWidth(null),icon.getImage().getHeight(null));
        setIcon(icon);
        setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
        setIconTextGap(0);
        setBorderPainted(true);
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setText(null);
    }

    public void setEnabled(Boolean b){
        if (b){
            setBackground(Color.black);
        } else {
            setBackground(Color.gray);
        }
        super.setEnabled(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: A side note: You could do `setBackground(b ? Color.black : Color.gray);` as well.

Comment: ah yea that's a good idea. Out of curiosity, is that syntax more efficient from a resource perspective or is it just a style thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change

```
public void setEnabled(Boolean b){
```

to

```
public void setEnabled(boolean b){
                       ^
```

(By using [`Boolean`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) instead of `boolean` you're *overloading* the method instead of *overriding* it.)

---

I encourage you to always annotate methods intended to override another method with `@Override`. If you had done it in this case, the compiler would have complained and said something like

> The method `setEnabled(Boolean)` of type `ImageButton` must override or implement a supertype method.

Comment: ahh thanks that works. Just out of curiosity, what happens when I capitalize the B and why does it work with a capital B if i just change the name of the method to something unique?

Comment: For each primitive (`boolean`, `int`, `float` and so on) there is an object counter part (`Boolean`, `Integer`, `Float` etc). In some cases they are treated similarly through auto-boxing. When overriding methods however, they are regarded as completely different types.

Comment: yea I had @override in there. My IDE was giving an error that said "Method does not override method from superclass." which I didn't understand at the time.

Answer (score 2):

Try without the capital letter in Boolean: there is difference between Boolean and boolean, so the signature is different:

```
public void setEnabled(boolean b)
```

Boolean with the capital letter is a Class.
boolean is a primitive type of the language.
(The same is for int vs Integer, double vs Double, etc)

Comment: I suggest you strike *It should work* and change Object to class.